# Javascript Code improvement - Integer factorial

Tags: javascript, algorithm, factorial

I am learning to code with Javascript and one exercise is about returning the factorial of a provided integer. For example: 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120

I came up with a result and it was accepted. However, I am not so sure it would be the most efficient way of solving this.

Anyone would have any tips on how to improve this code?

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var array = [];  
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    var multi = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        multi *= array[i];
    }
    return multi;
}
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: why you need in _array_ variable?

Comment: This really should be on code review. But searching should also produce many variations, some of which are sure to be improvements by one criterion or another.

Comment: I would call properly indenting the braced statements a significant improvement.

Comment: @Grundy, I am still learning so it helps me to visualize what I am doing. Hopefully soon enough I will write more concisely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several approaches to get a solution.

1. by iteration

   ```
   function f(n) {
       var r = n;
       while (--n) {
           r *= n;
       }
       return r;
   }
   ```
2. by recursion

   ```
   function f(n) {
       return n === 0 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1);
   }
   ```

   or a very short version

   ```
   function f(n) {
       return +!~-n || n * f(n - 1);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
var ans=1;
for (i=1;i<=num;i++)//for(i=num;i>=1;i--)
{
    ans=ans*i;
}
return ans;
```

Comment: A while loop is a little less code: `var n = 5, y = n; while (--n) y *= n;` but effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this kind of recursive method

```
function f(p) {
    if (p==1) return;
    p -= 1;
    x = x * p;
    f(p);        
}
```

A corrected version *(with comments)*:

```
function f(p) {
    if (p == 0) return 1;    /* 0! == 1 by definition,    */
    return p * f(p - 1);     /* otherwise p! = p * (p-1)! */
}
```